# How do write XML with decimal style entities with XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

For compatibility reasons I want to generate the exact same XML as another application with C# XmlWriter.

However I can not control the way the xml entities are written : XmlWriter use hexadecimal style (&#x20AC) and I want decimal style (&#8364).

How do I output decimal style with XmlWriter?

**Sample Code**

```
XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
  Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"),
};

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings))
{
  writer.WriteElementString("test", "€");
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><test>&#x20AC;</test>
```

Comment: What is the encoding used for the XML the other application writes?

Comment: The encoding is iso-8859-1

Comment: But you're saying the other application writes the output as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><test>&#8364;</test>`?

Comment: Interesting question : the "normal" diacritics characters use iso-8859-1 encoding and are not transformed into XML entities

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings))
    {
        string s = AntiXssEncoder.XmlEncode("€");
        writer.WriteStartElement("test");
        writer.WriteRaw(s);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

as the AntiXssEncoder uses decimal encoding. You would have to do it with `WriteRaw` because the XmlEncode already encodes everything in xml.

Don't do:

```
        string s = AntiXssEncoder.XmlEncode("€");
        writer.WriteElementString("test", s);
```

Or your output will escape the '&' character to `&amp;#8364;`